# rejoin files after split cli linux

Tags: file

I have a file which was split into 600 meg pieces

how do I join then back to original?

command was used:

```
split -b 600m image.iso
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat x* >> new.iso
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine so I deleted mine.